# Unable to reuse the same driver between two subs

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping

I've created a macro using selenium to get the links of different posts from a website and parse the title of each post after navigating to their target page. My first example just does the thing as expected which is written using a single sub.

> I would like to modify my macro using two subs and reusing the same driver between two subs like what I've tried in my second example.

Working one (using single sub):

```
Sub FetchLinks()
    Const link$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object
    Dim itmLink As Variant, R&, iDic As Object
    Set iDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With driver
        .get link
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".summary .question-hyperlink", timeout:=10000)
            iDic(post.Attribute("href")) = 1
        Next post

        For Each itmLink In iDic.keys
            driver.get itmLink
            Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("h1 > a.question-hyperlink").Text
        Next itmLink
    End With
End Sub
```

Can't make it work (tried to pass driver in another sub in order to reuse it):

```
Sub FetchLinks()
    Const link$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver, post As Object

    With driver
        .get link
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".summary .question-hyperlink", timeout:=10000)
            FetchData driver, post.Attribute("href")
        Next post
    End With
End Sub

Sub FetchData(ByRef driver, ByRef nlink As String)
    Dim elem As Object

    With driver
        .get nlink
        Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("h1 > a.question-hyperlink").Text
    End With
End Sub
```

***How can I share chromedriver between two subs in order to scrape some content from inner pages?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get a stale element reference as in the inner sub you are navigating away from the landing page. You then try to continue to reference this page in the outer loop. Put the links into a dictionary and loop that. Also, pass `ByVal`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FetchLinks()
    Const link$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim driver As ChromeDriver, post As Object, key As Variant
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"): Set driver = New ChromeDriver
    With driver
        .get link

        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".summary .question-hyperlink", timeOut:=10000)
            dict(post.Attribute("href")) = 1
        Next
        For Each key In dict.keys
            FetchData driver, key
        Next key
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub FetchData(ByVal driver As ChromeDriver, ByVal nlink As String)
    With driver
        .get nlink
        Debug.Print .FindElementByCss("h1 > a.question-hyperlink").Text
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yup, It is working in the right way. I have two quick questions (very small) on this. 1. Did it work as a variant when you use this `ByVal driver`? 2. Why you used byval instead of byref? I could understand that `nlink` is different from `link` so you used byval but aint `driver` is the same in both the subs then why `ByVal driver`? Always a pleasure to find you in the loop. Thanks again.

Comment: I use ByVal because you don't alter the value of either variable inside the called sub and I simply forgot to put the data type (my bad) for driver. It would be implicitly called as variant which would work but I guess also as Chromedriver for explicit typing.

Comment: I have updated to pass as ChromeDriver rather than variant.

Comment: So, when using like `ByVal driver As ChromeDriver`, it doesn't require to instantiate the chromedriver again, right? I asked too many questions coz I never have learnt the basics.

Comment: No it doesn't require instantiation. If you notice I changed your auto-instantiations to explicit instantiations. Don't worry, ByVal and ByRef /Pointers is my weak area. I usually ask the [ducks](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) - they're gurus.

Comment: you could read the bytecomb series starting with https://bytecomb.com/vba-internals-whats-in-a-variable/   https://bytecomb.com/category/programming/vba/